# How to get the first row number after the last protected range of a Google Sheet using App Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to get the first row number after the last protected range of a Google Sheet using App Scripts. Please note that I have several protected ranges in my Google Sheets. My code is as follows but not working?

```
var protections = sheetm.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
var len = protections.length; //last protection
var lastRow = protections[len].getRange().getLastRow();
var desiredRow = lowRow + 1;
```

Comment: Please show what you tried as well include a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: When adding code usually is better to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

Unfortunately, the other solution will only work for some cases.

The **last** protection object in the `protections` array **does not** mean that it contains the last protected row of the sheet.

---

See example below:

[image: example]

In the screenshot there are three different protected ranges.
But the protected ranges are not ranked based on the last protected row. Namely, if you compute the last protected row for every range in this example you will get this:

```
[121.0, 18.0, 36.0]
```

The last element of this array is `36`, but this is **not** the last protected row of the sheet which is actually `121`.

---

In order to find the last protected row of the sheet, you need to find the last protected row of every protected range and then get the maximum value:

```
const lastRows = [];
protections.forEach(pr=>lastRows.push(pr.getRange().getLastRow()));
const maxRow = Math.max(...lastRows);
```

---

### Solution:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const protections = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  const lastRows = [];
  protections.forEach(pr=>lastRows.push(pr.getRange().getLastRow()));
  const maxRow = Math.max(...lastRows);
  Logger.log(maxRow);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that your codde is throwing an error because the JavaScript indexes for collections and arrays are `0` based.

Try replacing this

```
var len = protections.length; //last protection
var lastRow = protections[len].getRange().getLastRow();
```

by

```
var len = protections.length; //last protection
var lastRow = protections[len - 1].getRange().getLastRow();
```